# Passenger error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm getting this error with Passenger:

```
https://github.com/huerlisi/PDFKit.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

When I run cap deploy (I'm using capistrano), it's saying that it's bundling the gem, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing gems from a git source, you will need to install them using `bundle install` as the error says. The contents of them are usually saved in `~/.bundler` and loaded in from there according to the specific version saved in `Gemfile.lock`.

What could be happening is that your application does not have a valid `Gemfile.lock` to latch on to and uses system gems by default.

What does `bundle check` show on your installed app?

It is not uncommon to have gems installed for the wrong version of ruby if you're using something like `rvm`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the huerlisi who's PDFKit branch you're using. I just want to tell you that you should consider switching back to the original branch at https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit as I'm not maintaining my branch, and the 'always render as PDF' bug has finally being fixed:-)